# Keep adding integers from an array to reach a specific max and check weather its possible to reach this number using those fixed values from an array

Tags: java, arrays, while-loop, sum

Example input: 
food menu in cent so 599 is $5.99 dollars 
599
600
788
277

Max price target is 10000 in cents which equal ($100.00)

I need my program to check weather I can spend 10000 from buying off the food menu, if i cant then it will simply return that we cant spend 10000 exactly from this menu

```
while ( sum != total) { 
for(int k=0; k < array.length;) { 
    //System.out.println(array[k]);
    sum += array[k];
    k++;
    }
}
```

I'm trying to use a while loop that will keep adding those prices from an array and check if sum = total (which is the target spending limit). Im not sure how to implement this while loop. Any tips?

I did some changes to my while loop

```
while ( sum <= total) { 
for(int k=0; k < array.length;) { 
    System.out.println(array[k]);
    sum += array[k];
    k++;
    }
    if (sum == total) { 
        break;
    }
}
```

My output is sum: 10520 
while it should stop at 10000 and say that we could spend 10000, or stops when it exceeds 10000 and return false for exceeding

Comment: What exactly is the problem with the code you've provided? Based on what you've described, it looks to me as though you just need a check when the while loop breaks, and perhaps make it while(sum <= total), as it is possible that if it doesn't add up to the amount you're looking for it will exceed it and loop infinitely.

Comment: while ( sum <= total) { 
 for(int k=0; k < array.length;) { 
  System.out.println(array[k]);
  sum += array[k];
  k++;
  }
  if (sum == total) { 
   break;
  }
 }  this one loop give me sum: 10520 while it should stop when it exceeds 10000 or when it sum == 10000

Comment: Add k++ to your for loop, like this: for(int k=0;k<array.length;k++), and remove it from the end after the sum += array[k]. Other than that, how does this loop behave? did you test it?

Comment: This is actually a more complicated problem if you want to see if there is a non-sequential combination of items that equals the desired amount.

Comment: I tested it it gives me 10520 for the sum.

Comment: Do you have any tips on how to do it? @DanielNugent

Comment: Just posted an answer below for sequential sum solution, and a link to a solution for a similar problem for non-sequential sum, which is a much harder problem.

Comment: @Mufassa, did the answer below help you solve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

If sequential sum is acceptable, you could do it as below.  The idea is that you move forward as long as you are below the amount, if you go over the limit subtract the first in the current set, and then continue to move forward.  At each point check if you have the exact amount.
This accounts for the fact that the set that equals the total could be in the middle, excluding values from either end, or it could be the last items in the list.

```
    int sum = 0 ;
    int j = 0;
    Arrays.sort(array);
    for (int i = 0 ; i < array.length ; i++) {
        while (j < array.length &&  sum < 10000) {
            sum += array[j] ;
            j++;
        }           
        if (sum == 10000) {
            return true ;
        }
        sum -= array[i] ;
    }

    return false;
```

For non-sequential, you would need to do something like this:
https://gist.github.com/dmnugent80/65b75fcca0549d38d0ba

Edit:  I see now that you're trying to cycle through the list more than once.  Taking from your original example, you could do something like this:

```
while ( sum <= total) { 
  for(int k=0; k < array.length; k++) { 
    System.out.println(array[k]);
    sum += array[k];

    if (sum == total) { 
        return true;
    }
    else if (sum > total) { 
        return false;
    }
  }
}
```